# Difference in <$> and fmap

Tags: haskell

I have a line of code:

```
(++) <$> Just "Hallo" <*> Just "Du"
```

which outputs `Just "HalloDu"`

In "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good" I learned that `<$>` and `fmap` are the same and indeed I ghci outputs the same type signature to me. Nevertheless, when I write:

```
fmap (++) Just "Hallo" <*> Just "Du"
```

Where is the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes `<$>` and `fmap` are the same thing but you are using them in different expressions.

```
(++) <$> Just "Hallo" <*> Just "Du"
```

is equivalent to:

```
(++) `fmap` Just "Hallo" <*> Just "Du"
```

moving `fmap` in infix position yields:

```
fmap (++) (Just "Hallo") <*> Just "Du"
```

This is due to operator precedence and why `<$>` is more readable most of the time.

Note that in your expression:

```
fmap (++) Just "Hallo" <*> Just "Du"
```

you are passing `3` arguments to `fmap` (`(++)`, `Just` and `"Hallo"`),
so the type doesn't match what `<*>` wants.

You want to pass only two arguments: `(++)` and `Just "Hallo"`.

Comment: Another subtlety worth mentioning: `fmap` and `(<$>)` have different fixities, so there still may be situations where putting `fmap` infix is different than putting `(<$>)` infix.

Comment: @DanielWagner, pre-AMP it would have made a lot of sense to give `liftM` and `ap` fixity declarations. It's not worth it now.

Comment: Ok, now I get my error in mind. I kind of considered data constructors as just container names for value(s) and there for didn't think about brackets. But data constructors are functions on it's own aren't they?

Comment: Yes, data constructors are functions.